# Can't access all columns via Data Browser

Tags: parse-platform

I'm having some trouble accessing two columns on my User Data via the Data Browser. I have data assigned to users ("country" and "region") which are showing up in data exports, but I can't view those fields via the Parse provided tools.

I'm hesitant from messing with those columns too much, since I have about 400 users and I'd have to re-enter all the column data manually if I manage to delete them or re-upload the user base again.

Let me know if any of this is unclear, or if I'm missing something REALLY simple. Kinda stumped here.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried quitting the browser and going in again?  Maybe just your instance of the app has run amok.

Comment: @danh Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately I checked in chrome/IE/Firefox on windows, and on chrome with my Mac with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it has to do with a schema update from a few months back. In my case, the missing columns didn't cause my app to break, so I didn't notice until the reporting fields went missing.

Anyway, check out this link and follow the directions, and you should be all set:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1522969234633526/

Good luck!